# Is it possible to update a file's content in Google Drive (knowing only the filename, not the file's unique fileId) using only one API call?

Tags: rest, google-drive-api

I believe I can do this in two steps (i.e., two REST calls): 1) list the files in a folder on Google Drive getting the fileId of an existing file, and 2) Use update to replace the contents of the file referenced by fileId with a new contents. However, it would seem like I should be able to do this in a single step, with the insert REST call. I can't however see any parameters on the insert call that would allow this. When I try just inserting multiple files with the same title, I get something like this in my Google Drive folder:

```
Test.txt 
Test.txt (1) 
Test.txt (2) 
etc.
```

Is it possible to replace Test.txt with just a single Google Drive REST call (presuming I don't already know the fileId of Test.txt, I just know it's name/title)?

Comment: I stumble on this before and the answer is no :(

Comment: Why vote it down? It seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: I didn't do. I was having the same question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is indeed "no". It's important to understand that Google Drive files are identified using their opaque ID, and that the title is simply a non-unique property, alongside parent, mime-type, etc.